# Install MikTeX failed, cannot find the detailed information for errors

Tags: miktex, installing

I have been using MiKTeX together with TeXMaker for some years. The combination is great.

Some days ago I bought a new laptop and tried to install MiKTeX in the new computer. The installation failed. The error message is:

> permission denied

My new computer has Windows 10 and McAfee. Following some suggestions in web I turned off McAfee. However, I got the same error message.

The detailed message is shown to be located in `C:\user\(username)\AppData\local\temp\mik16704\readme.txt`.

The trouble is that there is no subfolder `\mik16704` under `\AppData\local\temp`, therefore I cannot see the detailed information in `readme.txt`.

Comment: are installing it with admin rights or common user?

Comment: Avoid installing with admin rights unless you must. Meanwhile, if all else fails, try the portable version and install it in your user home directory. As far as I can tell, it does the same things as the installed version does, but you'd have to point Texmaster to the miktex executables.

Comment: There is only a 32 bit portable version in the MIKTEX web page, and my windows system is of 64 bit. I will try to add another user account of the type Standard instead of admin to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I succeeded in installing MixTex! I created another user account without admin priorities. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I had a similar problem many years ago. To find the solution that best fits your exact situation, search the Internet for "Windows denied access to temp folder". This goes back to at least Windows 7. It is not specific to Miktex.

Gist of the problem: Some downloads are packaged as self-extracting executables. They first unpack themselves, then run the installer. The unpacked files go to a temp directory. But Windows won't let you run the installer from there, and may not even allow an executable to be placed there.

<s>You can probably unpack the downloaded file manually, on your Desktop or some other convenient location. If the built-in unzipper cannot do it, try the portable version of 7-zip (the file may be a 7-zip type). Then, once unpacked, find the installer executable and run it.</s>

Comment: I tried to use 7-zip to unpack the .exe file. It turns out the file cannot be extracted. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I could not unpack it either, even using 7zip. But I managed to run the 64-bit installer (not the net installer, but the one that's around 190Mb) on Windows 10, just now. Frsh download. I asked for user install (just me) rather than system-wide install. Ran smoothly. I stopped it while it was downloading the b-packages, since I already have Miktex and did not wish to over-write anything. So, in your case it may be a folder permissions problem. My Win10 was migrated from Win8.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug or something MikTeX and Windows 10 have to pay attention. I can only install MikTeX as a standard user not as an admin. For many of us we work in our spare time with personal computer we are the only user with admin priorities. Many thanks to Stefan and Robt A for your kind help!